# How to get nested-groups with regexp

Tags: python, regex, nested-groups

I need your help with following regex. 
I have a text

```
"[Hello|Hi]. We are [inviting | calling] you at position [[junior| mid junior]|senior] developer."
```

using regex I want to get

```
[Hello|Hi]
[inviting | calling]
[[junior| mid junior]|senior]
```

the following rexeg `(\[[^\[$\]\]]*\])`

gives me

`[Hello|Hi]
[inviting | calling]
[junior| mid junior]`

so how should I fix it to get correct output?

Comment: The re module doesn't support regex recursion, which is needed for this kind of task. You might want to take a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Comment: Most implementations of regular expressions aren't up to the task of parsing nested expressions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la PCRE is an extension  to regular expressions, which is why the PCRE "regex" solution below looks nothing like the regular expression grammar you're used to.

Comment: The solution u accepted  will work only for 3 levels.its not a generic solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's define your string and import re:

```
>>> s = "[Hello|Hi]. We are [inviting | calling] you at position [[junior| mid junior]|senior] developer."
>>> import re
```

Now, try:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\[ (?:[^][]* \[ [^][]* \])* [^][]*  \]', s, re.X)
['[Hello|Hi]', '[inviting | calling]', '[[junior| mid junior]|senior]']
```

#### In more detail

Consider this script:

```
$ cat script.py
import re
s = "[Hello|Hi]. We are [inviting | calling] you at position [[junior| mid junior]|senior] developer."

matches = re.findall(r'''\[       # Opening bracket
        (?:[^][]* \[ [^][]* \])*  # Zero or more non-bracket characters followed by a [, followed by zero or more non-bracket characters, followed by a ]
        [^][]*                    # Zero or more non-bracket characters
        \]                        # Closing bracket
        ''',
        s,
        re.X)
print('\n'.join(matches))
```

This produces the output:

```
$ python script.py
[Hello|Hi]
[inviting | calling]
[[junior| mid junior]|senior]
```

Comment: OP is asking for nested brackets, as soon as you add a third level this won't work anymore.

Comment: The extension to three levels is obvious.  If he were to need arbitrarily deep nesting, that would be an issue.  The OP may want to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple `stack` to do this instead of `recursive regex`

```
x="[Hello|Hi]. We are [inviting | calling] you at position [[junior| mid junior]|senior] developer.[sd[sd[sd][sd]]]"
l=[]
st=[]
start=None
for i,j in enumerate(x):
    if j=='[':
        if j not in st:
            start = i
        st.append(j)
    elif j==']':
        st.pop()
        if not st:
            l.append(x[start:i+1])
print l
```

Ouput: `['[Hello|Hi]', '[inviting | calling]', '[[junior| mid junior]|senior]', '[sd[sd[sd][sd]]]']`

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following code with [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/2016.10.22) with a PCRE-like `r'\[(?:[^][]++|(?R))*]'` regex:

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = "[Hello|Hi]. We are [inviting | calling] you at position [[junior| mid junior]|senior] developer."
>>> r = regex.compile(r'\[(?:[^][]++|(?R))*]')
>>> print(r.findall(s))
['[Hello|Hi]', '[inviting | calling]', '[[junior| mid junior]|senior]']
>>>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TxaJhp/1).

The `\[(?:[^][]++|(?R))*]` matches a `[`, then zero or more sequences of 1+ chars other than `]` and `[` OR the whole bracketed expression `[...]`, and then a closing `]`.